# Shooting object based on arm rotation in libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to shoot an object(a spell) depending on the rotation of the players arm. The spell is supposed to come out of the hand and shoot towards where the mouse cicked(the arm rotates and points to where the mouse is). This is how the arm rotates in game.

```
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    tmp.x = screenX;
    tmp.y = screenY;
    tmp.z = 0;
    cam.unproject(tmp);
    rot = MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * MathUtils.atan2((float)tmp.y - (float)player.getArmSprite().getY() - player.getArmSprite().getHeight(),
            tmp.x -player.getArmSprite().getX() - player.getArmSprite().getWidth());
    if (rot < 0) rot += 360;

    //Last right or left means if hes looking left or right
    if(player.lastRight)
        player.setObjectRotation(rot + 80);
     if(player.lastLeft)
        player.setObjectRotation(-rot - 80);
```

And this is how the spell is supposed to shoot based off rotation

```
    //destination is a vector of where on screen the mouse was clicked
    if(position.y < destination.y){
        position.y += vel.y * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }
    if(position.x < destination.x){
        position.x += vel.x * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }
```

However this is very wonky and never really reacts the way it supposed to with a few exceptions. It fires from the hand and then if the y axis is equal it completely evens out and goes till it reaches the x position, I want it to fire from the hand to the position clicks perfectly straight from point a to point b, this is clearly a rotation problem that I just can't seem to figure out how to tackle.

Here is an image of what is happening

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTUzM.png)

The red indicates where I clicked, as you can see it reached the x pos first and now is traveling to the y when it should have reached the x and y pos of where I clicked first

Any help with this problem is extremely appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem you are having.  What do you mean by "wonky and never really reacts the way it supposed to"?  Please be more specific, like "It only moves halfway" or "the arm spins around in a circle and fires out the screen into the user's nose"

Comment: @RyanBemrose I edited it

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty bad at radians and tangents but luckily we have vectors.

Since you have the `rot` ation in degrees of the arm. I advice to use Vectors to use for any Vector related math now.

```
//A vector pointing up
Vector2 direction = new Vector2(0, 1);

//Let's rotate that by the rotation of the arm
direction.rotate(rot);
```

Now direction is the direction the arm is pointing. If your `rot`ation is calculated where `up = 0`. So you might need to rotate it 180, 90 or -90 degrees. Or in the case you did something silly any degrees.

Your spell should have a Vector too for it's position. Set that to the hand or wherever you want to start from. Now all you need to do is scale that `direction` since it's currently has a length of 1. If you want to move 5 units each frame you can do `direction.scl(5)` now it is of length 5. But technically speaking it's no direction anymore now everybody calls it `velocity` so let's do.

```
//when you need to fire
float speed = 5;
Vector2 velocity = direction.cpy().scl(speed);

//update
position.add(velocity);
draw(fireballImage, position.x, position.y);
```

I copied direction first, otherwise it would also be scaled. Then I just added the velocity to the position and draw using that Vector.

And to show Vectors are awesome you should see this awesome badlogic vs mouse program I created. https://github.com/madmenyo/FollowMouse there are just a view lines of my own code. It just takes a little bit of vector knowledge and it's very readable.